# Solr Dismax using % in mm parameter give error

Tags: apache, solr, full-text-search, edismax, dismax

I am trying to use the mm (Minimum Should Match) parameter with the dismax parser. If I do just mm=2 or any other int value it seems to work fine. But if I try and add a percent as shown in the able, say mm=60%, then I get an "invalid digit" error for the query. How do I actually use the percentage for mm?

[Solr ref guide mm table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doXX9.png)

(running solr 7.6 btw)

Comment: Do you have an example of your actual query string? Make sure you've escaped '%' properly, as it's the beginning of an URL parameter escape code as well, which means that your query could end up sending a random character instead of what you think it's sending.

Comment: How do you escape it? I tried \% as I know escapes characters in a lot of programming languages but this is different I guess as that didn't help.

Comment: `%25` is the escape code for `%`. A quick way to find out is to open your browser's developer tools (F12 for Chrome on Windows), go to "Console" and type `encodeURIComponent('%')`. It'll return the encoded version of whatever you gave it.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the help!